# Add dropdown toggle to ul.submenu

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I would like to add a simple toggle for sub-menu class. I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul .sub-menu").parent().closest("li").append('<span class="submenu-toggle">▼</span>');
  $("ul .sub-menu").hide();
  $(".submenu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul .sub-menu").toggle();
    $(this).html('▲');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub-item</li>
      <li>Sub-item</li>
    </ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `.sub-menu` is a *sibling* of the `span` that's clicked, so you need to use `siblings()`, not `children()`. Also, you can just use `closest()` alone instead of `parent().closest()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul .sub-menu").hide().closest("li").append('<span class="submenu-toggle">▼</span>');

  $(".submenu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").toggle();
    $(this).html(function(i, h) {
      return h == '▲' ? '▼' : '▲';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub-item</li>
      <li>Sub-item</li>
    </ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Also note that I included the logic which toggles the arrow based on the state of the menu.